# Вопрос по DNS

Tags: домен, сервер, dns

Здравствуйте
У меня есть выделенный сервер, на котором есть сайт domain.com (пример). В панели управления доменом регистратора доменов прописаны DNS адреса хостера:

```
    ns1.hosting.com      ns2.hosting.com
```

Для домена добавлены 2 А записа с IP адресом сервера.

```
    domain.com    178.ХХ.13.ХХ    *.domain.com    178.ХХ.13.ХХ
```

Все работает. 
Вопрос:
Если я куплю еще один домен и DNS адреса поставлю не хостера, а поставлю свою поддомены (не DNS), типа:

```
    ns1.domain.com      ns2.domain.com
```

То сработает ли трассировка и будет ли доступный сайт на сервере ( VirtualHost будет предварительно обавлен ) ?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS занимается сопоставлением имен и IP-адресов.
Если Вы будете использовать свои DNS-сервера, то их необходимо будет настроить их на обмен информацией с DNS-серверами хостера. В противном случае, никто не сможет попасть на Ваш сайт (на новом домене) по доменному имени, т.к. внешние сервера не будут знать связки IP=DNS-имя, т.е. не будут знать где искать Ваш сайт.